# Update an object in an activity from another class without using the activity's name

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments

I want to update an object of type ArrayList> in another 2 activities from this class I think i can do this by using Activity's name.Object.someupdate but i can't do this because i want to use this with 2 activities and can't pass the object of type (Playlist Activity) as a parameter as i may use this with other activities in the future
below is the declaration of the class constructor

```
public void getAlbumList(String path, ArrayList<ArrayList<Song>> songslist)
```

Comment: Create a helper class (POJO) and use it to manage the `ArrayList`. Probably a good idea to follow the singleton pattern so you only ever have one instance. You can then get access to the list from any `Activity` in your app.

Comment: @Squonk can u plz give me an example i am really new to android i am unable to implement what u r saying